# Centralizer, normalizer, and center of a dihedral group

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory

Let $A := \{1, r, r^2,..., r^{n-1}\}$. Compute $C_{D_{2n}}(A), N_{D_{2n}}(A),$ and $Z(D_{2n})$.

So far I figured that all of the rotations are in the centralizer/normalizer, because all rotations commute with each other. After that I'm pretty stuck... Could anybody give some help?

Comment: For the centralizer/normalizer, remark that $A$ is a subgroup of index $2$ in $D_{2n}$.

Comment: What does an "index" of a subgroup mean? Is it its cardinal?

Comment: No it is not, but it is related. Strictly speaking if $G$ is a group and $H$ is a subgroup of $G$, the index of $H$ in $G$ is $[G:H]:=|G/H|$ the cardinality of the left-cosets for $H$ in $G$. When $G$ is finite you have $[G:H]=|G|/|H|$.

Answer (score 1):

For the center of $D_{2n}$, you have two cases. If $n$ is odd, then the center is trivial. If $n$ is even, then the center consists of two elements: the identity and $r^{n/2}$.

For the other parts of your question, make use of the fact that $A$ is a normal subgroup.